# Bootstrap based restaurant menu row not respected

Tags: row

I created a webpage for a restaurant, with back-end admin panel. From the admin panel I can upload the menus, foods and drinks.

I have two problems: 
1. After the upload of the menu, every time a space somewhere remain empty. 
2. In the drink section (which has the same code as the food section) rows are not respected.

I attach pictures and you can understand better.

[First problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGVoS.png)
[Second problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szZpe.jpg)

Comment: looks like a css issue to me.

Comment: Probably yes. But I can't find it.  I will link the website, probably you can find something.

The drink image problem has been solved by deleting img section. But the gap is still there:

http://ladiavolorestaurants.ro/dev/#!/ristopub/menu

Thank you!